# How to sort positive and negative percentages in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have this function but It don't sort my percentage correctly:

```js
var arrayWithTheSortedPrice = [10, 12, 18.5, -56, -5, -12.5];
arrayWithTheSortedPrice.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(arrayWithTheSortedPrice)
```

Its sort like this:

```
[18.5,12,10,-56,-12.5,-5]
```

I want this as result:

```
[18.5,12,10,-5,-12.5,-56]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sort function is a little off.  You can do this with numbers very easily...

```js
var arrayWithTheSortedPrice = [10, 12, 18.5, -56, -5, -12.5];
arrayWithTheSortedPrice.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a;
});

console.log(arrayWithTheSortedPrice)
```

The sort function expects a negative value, a positive value, or zero, and then decides how to sort the array based on that result.  This simply says to sort numbers in descending order.

Comment: Thanks it worked! The only thing I need to your answer is this `return b[1] - a[1];` because In mine code it's a 2D array

Comment: Okay - that makes sense.  With the example it didn't, but that explains it.

Comment: Yes my fault I let the 2d array go in the example. But thanks for explaining to me!

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)